# Compare if statement in Python

Tags: python

```
from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input

Inventory1 = ["Rice", "Maze", "Oil", "Toothpaste", "Beans", "Cloth", "Pepper"]
print("Here are present items list information:", Inventory1)

CheckInv1 = input('Is this item present in the inventory: \n')

for CheckInv1 in Inventory1:
    if CheckInv1 == ("Rice", "Maze", "Oil", "Toothpaste", "Beans", "Cloth", "Pepper"):
        print("This item is present in the inventory list.")
        break
    else:
        print("User entered item is not present in the list.")
        break
```

**Question:** Even enter "Oil" text in code input, its still showing else print statement. 
If statement is not compared. Any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: `CheckInv1` *isn't* the tuple you are comparing it to; it may be *contained* in the tuple, though. You want `in`, not `==`.

Comment: you are comparing  string with the entire tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say, this code is **all** wrong:

1. You overwrite the value of `CheckInv1` that came from `input`,
   because you reuse the same name for for loop control variable;
2. You test `CheckInv1` for equality against a tuple of values, but
   `CheckInv1` is never going to be a tuple, so equality is not
   possible;
3. You put `break` in both branches of your `if`, so no matter if the
   `if` condition is true or not, your loop will end after first
   iteration.

What you really need to do is quite simple:

```
Inventory1 = ["Rice", "Maze", "Oil", "Toothpaste", "Beans", "Cloth", "Pepper"]
print("Here are present items list information:", Inventory1)

CheckInv1 = input('Is this item present in the inventory: \n')

if CheckInv1 in Inventory1:
    print("This item is present in the inventory list.")
else:
    print("User entered item is not present in the list.")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare an item with a tuple. This are different kinds, so if always evaluated as false.

```py
if CheckInv1 in ("Rice", "Maze", "Oil", "Toothpaste", "Beans", "Cloth", "Pepper"):
```

will check if what inside `CheckInv1` is an element of your tuple.

Also, notice you are disregarding from the input. inside for loop (`for CheckInv1 in Inventory1:`) `CheckInv1` is an item of the `Invenory1` you defined earlier and not user input.

If your intention was to check if user input is inside inventory, you should remove your for loop. If you want to do it for couple of times, use a flag (like boolean) to keep looping as long as it evaluated to true and ask user for another input inside the loop:

```py
from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input

Inventory1 = ["Rice", "Maze", "Oil", "Toothpaste", "Beans", "Cloth", "Pepper"]
print("Here are present items list information:", Inventory1)

CheckInv1 = input('Is this item present in the inventory: \n')
conLoop = True
while conLoop:
    if CheckInv1 in Inventory1:
        print("This item is present in the inventory list.")
        conLoop = False
    else:
        print("User entered item is not present in the list.")
        CheckInv1 = input('Is this item present in the inventory: \n')
```

this code keeps asking for user input until one of the products is in the inventory